# js asynchronous problem just work first neighbor

Tags: javascript

I want click neighbor and change the main country. I click first card ok no problem. but other cards not working. This is my code:

```
function renderNeighbors(data) {
    let html = "";
    for (let country of data) {
        html += `
                <div class="col-2 mt-2">
                    <div class="card click-change">
                        <img src="${country.flags.png}" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6 class="card-title neighborName">${country.name.common}</h6>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
    }

    document.querySelector("#neighbors").innerHTML = html;

    document.querySelector(".click-change").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let neighborName = document.querySelector(".neighborName").innerHTML;

        getCountry(neighborName);
    })
}
```

in photos I point red circle in my browser. that's only working card.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5VXU.png)

I want to click neighbors and change main country. but only work for first neighbor

here is my all html code https://pastebin.com/Sb9XWZhy

Comment: could you please post getCountry function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, the problem you are setting your event only for the first chosen element that matches your locator .

querySelector return only the first element that matches.

you should add the event for all of your nodes that match the locator.

It's supposed that querySelectorAll returns an array that you can loop over it like that.

```
for (let element of document.querySelectorAll(".click-change")){
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let neighborName = 
 element.children[1].children[0].innerHTML;//here I'm accessing the neighbourName from the element itself, I'm not sure about the indices but you can handle them yourself

            getCountry(neighborName);
        })
}
```